# Python test if an element is in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a python program call notepad.exe it not already running. Right now, I'm using psutil with

```
pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['name'])
if ("{'name': %s}"%SomeProcess) != str(pinfo):
   subprocess.call("%s"%SomeProcess, shell=True)
```

However, this won't work because the `subprocess.call` will call for every name on the list besides the one it is looking for.

Knowing how to use `subprocess` and some of `psutil` I should know this, but is there any way to see if a dictionary has a preset string in it with one line of code? Something like

```
pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['name'])
if pinfo contains "somename":
   do something
```

If this is possible, (99% sure it is.) can it be done without a loop? (I want to update the process list every second or so.)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Okay, probably should have given slightly more code, as that would have been relevant.

```
proc.as_dict()
```

by itself won't do anything, so I have this is a "for" loop.

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter(): 
    pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['name'])
```

How could I change that to output a dictionary, rather than a single line*, and would `pinfo.get('somename')` work on that created dictionary?

*If I use `print(pinfo)` it outputs one line. Something like `{'name': 'pythonw.exe'}`.

Comment: I think you'd be better off now to delete this question and ask a new one.  Get the title right, and include the relevant information, and not irrelevant information :)   The current question is getting worse, because you say "how can I change that to output a dictionary rather than a single line", when the code you have shown us doesn't output anything at all.  What do you mean by "output a dictionary"?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Perhaps I'll do that tomorrow. It's late where I am, so this stays as-is for tonight. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you want to do something like that:

```
names = set()
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
   names.add(proc.name())

if SomeProcess not in names:
   subprocess.call("%s"%SomeProcess, shell=True)
```

It does not make to much sense, to create a dictionary with one entry and what you really wanted to do was to scan all processes in your system (I guess). So you already mentioned the iter, only your question was a little weird. Using the set (names) makes the decision a little more performant. You also could use a list here.

Comment: I was getting `raise AccessDenied psutil.AccessDenied` so I put a `try: except:` function. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I did not test the code, just wrote it down.